# How to install Geolite2 on Piwik 3.0.2 (old version of Motomo)?

Tags: ftp, installation, matomo, geolite2

I have Piwik 3.0.2 and a tar ball of Geolite2_City. Can I install directly on my folders on server? Where I put this file?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use well formatted code and try to give a good description of your question so that others can understand and answer it. I suggest you to read the asking guidelines of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Matomo only got support for the new Maxmind Geoip format in Matomo 3.5.0 with the new `GeoIp2` plugin. So if you want to use it, you have to update to the latest version (which is anyway recommended because of security and bug fixes).

The only way to use new Geoip files with an older version is by using the unofficial `GeoIP2` plugin: https://github.com/diabl0/piwik-geoip2

Comment: I don't understand if exist a free release of Motomo.

Comment: Matomo is available for free under the GPL 3.0 license here: https://matomo.org/download